# Transfer image animation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two divs (parentDiv,childDiv). ParentDiv conatins multiple images so when user clicks on an image it should copy that image in childDiv (this can be achieved using jQuery clone function) but I want to animate the copying process like flying animation. I tried this but

```
var clonedImg = $("#img").clone().css("position", "absolute").css("opacity","0");
                $("#parent").append(clonedImg);
                clonedImg.animate({ 
                   opacity: 1,
                    top: '+=300'
                }, 5000, function () {
                    $("#child").append(clonedImg);
                });
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VvCXr/)

Answer (score 2):

The cloned element must be added to the DOM before performing animation:

```
  $("#btnTransfer").click(function () {
            var clonedImg = $("#img").clone();
            $("#child").append(clonedImg);
            clonedImg.css("position", "relative").animate({ opacity: 0.25,
                top: '+=50'
            }, 5000, function () {
                clonedImg.css("opacity", "1");
            });
        });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VvCXr/6/